# Display all blog articles of a specific user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4

The scenario: I have two tables: `UserProfiles` and `BlogArticles`. The blog article is inside UserProfile, so if I would like to get all blog articles of a specific user, I would type something like:

```
db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(x=> x.UserName == User.Idenity.Name).BlogArticles
```

However, I would like to do this using the `BlogArticles` table, that is, I would like to get BlogArticles that come from the same UserProfile, as following:

```
db.BlogArticles(x=> ...) // these should be from one user only.
```

**Solution1**
One way is to do it backwards, as following:

```
db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(d => d.BlogArticles.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id==BlogArticles) != null);
```

So, given a BlogArticle id, the UserProfile can be found.

However, how would I be able to get a list of articles that come from a particular userprofile using the BlogArticle table?

I've tried

```
db.BlogArticles.Where(x=> Functions.GetAuthor(x.Id) == User.Identity.Name).ToList()
```

but I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String      GetAuthor(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How can I solve this in a better way?

---

```
    [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogArtilce> BlogArticles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }


    //public DateTime Created = DateTime.Today;

}

    [Table("BlogArticle")]
public class BlogArticle
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public  int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual string Contents { get; set; }

    public virtual int Views { get; set; }

    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual string Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; } // this must be an int.

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BlogArticle> BlogArticles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show classes of UserProfile and BlogArticle? do they have PK FK relation

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, please see my newest edit.

Comment: @artem: You did not include the BlogArticle class.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, it's now fixed!

Comment: @Artem always post complete details which are required to answer the question

Comment: @Artem: Could you please share what fixed your issue? Looking at your classes there does not seem to be a way to refer to the parent object Author from the BlogArticle class. The only way you can know if a particular author created an article is if you simply refer to the Author's BlogArticle collection...???

Comment: @Paul Sasik, I think, as you mentioned, the only way to obtain if an author has created a blog article is by referring to Author's Blog Article collection. The problem I had was because before UserProfile has also a thing called "group" that also contained blog articles. But this is a bad way of creating collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. From your OP you already selected an author and should therefore have access to the author's id and the means to store it.

So, your code could look something like this, assuming that BlogArticles has a property named AuthorId:

```
int localAuthorId = ???; // assign from wherever you fetched it

// simpler filter:
db.BlogArticles.Where(x => x.AuthorId = localAuthorId).ToList()
```

Comment: You're assuming all id's are properly mapped in the model. You don't have to do that and then you are 'stuck' with just navigational properties.

Comment: @Maarten: I was assuming that there was a one-way reference from author to article, which it is since author contains a collection of articles. I also assumed that the Article class would have a way of referencing the parent/Author since that's the only way to solve the OP's problem. It turns out there is no such property. And the model does not lend itself to solving the issue in the manner the OP is trying since all articles are in buckets separated between authors.